# Why does `memmove` use `void *` as parameter instead of `char *`?

Tags: c, memmove

The definition of the c library function `memmove` is like the following:

```
void* memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    char *sc1;
    const char *sc2;

    sc1 = s1;
    sc2 = s2;
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering why do we need to use `void*` and `const void*` as the parameters' type. Why not directly `char*` and `const char*`?

## update

```
int test_case[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10};

memmove(test_case+4, test_case+2, sizeof(int)*4);
```

Output:
test_case = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10}

Comment: Because this isn't a string function but a memory one; using `void*` makes it Works with any kind of pointer and not `char*` ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void *` is the generic pointer type. `memmove` is supposed to manipulate memory regardless of what type of objects are in the memory.

Similarly for `memcpy`. Compare it with `strcpy` which uses `char *` parameters because it's supposed to manipulate strings.

Answer (score 6):

If `char*` and `const char*` are used, then we have to always cast to `char*` when invoking `memmove` on other types.

By using `void*` and `const void*`, we are able to write shorter code, and the casting has no performance overhead.